# Editing answered questions to alter the original meaning

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

[This](https://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/151/revisions) is the edit history of a closed question:
[How hard will it be to train my parrot to talk?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-hard-will-it-be-to-train-my-parrot-to-talk)

The question already had an accepted and voted answer. The edit made the answer redundant and also made the question increasingly broad and off topic.

This is not a question, but more a discussion to assist community members when making edits.

Answer (score 4):

Rollback. A question, especially one with answers, and **especially** one with an accepted answer, should not be altered so that the meaning has changed, and the answers were validated.

The solution is to rollback, and advise the OP to ask a new question if he has a different one, optionally linking to the old one as followup.

Comment: @Skippy: That's my assumption. `The solution is to rollback, and advise the OP to ask a new question`. All of this applies tenfolds if a *different user* does the edit.

Comment: I know the official MSO response for this (heck, I've answered this question there before), but having never participated in a private beta before, do you think more latitude should be given to help make questions on-topc while we are still sorting out what kind of questions we want?

Comment: @psubsee2003: No. Closing off-topic questions, and asking new on-topic questions are the best course of action. Especially in a private-beta where you want to set the ground rules for the community, and not allowing so-called "problematic" behavior.